# NameError in Projects#show with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to do this(the code below) in my **show.html.erb**, but it gives me this error:

> NameError in Projects#show

but this works fine in my **index.html.erb** which makes it even weirder?

```
<%= link_to 'Back', projects_path %>
 <% if project.user == current_user %>
   <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project) %></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
<% end %>
```

oh and by the way, I am using Devise and that is where this is coming from

```
<% if project.user == current_user %>
```

---

here is the full error:

NameError in Projects#show

undefined local variable or method `project' for #<#:0x007fd419297d00>
Extracted source (around line #30):

```
<%= link_to 'Back', projects_path %>
 <% if @project.user.id == current_user.id %>
  <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: show the full error stack

Comment: and controller code, this isn't extrasensory club

Comment: is `<% if project.user == current_user %>` is in `show.html.erb` ?

Comment: it is in both show and index, but it only works in the index. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is in `show.html.erb`, then make changes as :-

```
<%= link_to 'Back', projects_path %>
  <% if @project.user == current_user %>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(@project) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', @project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
<% end %>
```